# Making a static library

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, static-libraries, static-linking

I am attempting to make a static library for a piece of code of mine, but cannot figure out how to get it to work.

**The exact question is:**

What exactly do I need to export and what do I need to import in order to get it to work?:

**What I did:**

I slapped a `__declspec(dllexport)` on the class and the 2 function that I need to access from within the class.

```
    __declspec(dllexport) class MyClass {
    public:
    ...
    __declspec(dllexport) int functionA() {
...
}
    __declspec(dllexport) int functionB() {
...
}
    ...
    };
```

I then created a header where I import the library (same architecture):

`#pragma comment(lib, "MyLib.lib")`

And I redefined the class and imported only the things I previously exported (and put them inside a namespace)

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    __declspec(dllimport) class MyClass {
    public:
    __declspec(dllimport) int functionA();
    __declspec(dllimport) int functionB();
    };
}
```

And I attempted to call them, only to be met with `unresolved external symbol` errors

`MyClass m; int a = m.FunctionA();`

**So,**

Do I need to export more code? do I need to export constructors? Do I need to change the function prototype?

Thanks!

Comment: [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=vs-2019) is (only) used for import libraries of DLLs. Drop those, and the `__declspec(dllimport)` counterparts. Then everything compiled with external linkage will be available in the static `.lib` as per the language rules.

Comment: Oh, I see. So how do I link them then? I tried using nothing and also putting them in a `extern "C"` scope, but it also does not work

Comment: The sad truth of this is that most sources don't recommend exporting classes at all, only C-style functions. You can make it work but programs using your static library better be built with the same compiler version. Otherwise you might get "undefined behaviour", i.e. unpredictable bugs with perhaps not even an error message.

Comment: A static library is essentially a collection of object files. If you can link the program when compiling the files individually, you'll still be able to link when grouping some of the object files into a `.lib` file. What exactly "*does not work*" in your case is hard to guess without a lot more context and details.